# Creating a directive with a variable element type

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a directive that will change the html element type (h1/h2/h3) by using a drop down selector of "Large", "Medium", "Small".  I want it to also retain attributes on the element.  I have created a fiddle of this example:  http://jsfiddle.net/H63Z3/1/

Angular:

```
angular.module('app', [])
        .controller('example', function ($scope) {
            $scope.type = 'h2';
        })
        .directive('changeType', function ($compile) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
                    scope.$watch('type', function () {
                        var attrs = element[0].attributes;
                        var newElement = $('<' + scope.type + '>').text(element.text());
                        for (var i = 0; i < attrs.length; i++) {
                            newElement.attr(attrs.item(i).name, attrs.item(i).value);
                        }
                        element.replaceWith(newElement);
                        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                    });
                }
            };
        });
```

HTM & L:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="example">
    <select ng-model="type" ng-options="k as v for (k,v) in { h1: 'Large', h2: 'Medium', h3: 'Small' }"></select>
    <h1 change-type>Text</h1>

    <div>{{ type }}</div>
</div>
```

The problem I see is that the element property is not being updated properly in Angular after a change is made by the drop down.  It seems that the directive is not reapplied to the new element.  I'm unsure if using a compile function is the right answer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this close to what you're looking for? [AngularJS - How do I change an element within a template that contains a data-binding?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299175/angularjs-how-do-i-change-an-element-within-a-template-that-contains-a-data-bi

Comment: Why dont you create an Element directive that depending on the input attribute changes the template? i.e. <headline type="h1"></headline>

Comment: @EdMeacham The solution in your link works, however it nests the changed element inside of the original which looks like: "<h1 change-type><h2>Text</h2></h1>".  I would like to have just a single header element on the page that changes so I can extract clean output markup.  The complication of doing it this way is that the element has to be destroyed and recreated with the directive still applied to that single header element.  This is the part that I'm not sure is possible but it seems that using element.replaceWith() should allow for that.  I'm not sure what I have wrong in my example.

Answer (score 9):

I just spent a little while working on what I decided to call a 'morphling' directive. It was pretty fun actually, and I'm quite pleased with the result. Note that this solution is pure Angular.

**Note**: I failed to notice when I first posted this that you required persistent attributes. I have since added that functionality. I add my attributes after compilation, but if you want to supply directives as attributes, you'd have to do it the other way around.

## HTML

```
<h1>AngularJS 'Morphling' Directive</h1>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="morphTest">
  <strong>Morphling directive type:</strong> <select ng-model="type" ng-options="tag as caption for (tag, caption) in { h1: 'Heading 1', h2: 'Heading 2', h3: 'Heading 3', li: 'List Item', quote: 'Quote', attrDemo: 'Attribute Persistence Demo' }"></select><br />
  <morphling type="type" attr="value">Normal <span style="color: red">{{bindingDemo}}</span> Works</morphling>
</div>
```

## LESS

```
html, body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #111;
}

quote {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px;
  font-style: italic;
  &:before,
  &:after {
    content: '"';
  }
}

attrDemo[attr="value"] {
  display: inline-block;
  color: blue;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

## Javascript

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('morphTest', function ($scope) {
    $scope.type = 'h2';
    $scope.bindingDemo = 'Binding';
  })
  .directive('morphling', function ($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
        var e = element;
        scope.$watch(attributes.type, function(type){
          type = !!type ? type : 'span';
          var e2 = $compile('<' + type + '>' + e.html() + '</' + type + '>')(scope);
          for(var a in attributes.$attr) {
            if(a.toLowerCase() != 'type')
              e2.attr(a, attributes[a]);
          }
          e.replaceWith(e2);
          e = e2;
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

## Demo

[CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/mirichan/pen/rsbpH)

Comment: Regarding @FLoG's 'answer' pointing out the flaw in this solution: if you put a scope variable in the directive and have an interval creep it up, it will creep up until the first change to `type`. Yes, it's a problem. If you need to account for that behaviour, you'll have to modify the `$compile` line substantially.

Comment: This solution is so close to working for me, but I'm having trouble getting additional attributes working when they are object literals. I'm a little confused about how angular handles objects when passed as attributes. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: As FloG pointed out, the binding doesn't completely work. Notice that I add the attributes back after compilation... it would need to be before, but I don't know if Angular even supports the kind of reflection needed to make this work properly. You'd need access to the entire string for each invocation of the directive. If you could get that from the directive, this solution could be improved.

Comment: Actually, it's definitely possible, because otherwise ngRepeat wouldn't be a thing. I think I should be able to fix this. I'll take a look later when I'm not still waking up :)

Comment: Thanks @scarl3tt, that would be awesome! I'll post if I uncover anything before you get to it.

Comment: Ok, figured it out. Just needed to add the actual string into the element declaration inside of $compile as you hinted at. I was getting stuck because I was trying to add the actual object instead of a string. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

@Michael Mroz

I would like to point out that the solution you proposed breaks the binding:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwLzQX

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('morphTest', function ($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.type = 'h2';
    $scope.bindingDemo = 'Binding';

    var i = 0;
    $interval(function() {
      $scope.bindingDemo = 'Binding ' + ++i;
    }, 1000);
  })
  .directive('morphling', function ($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
        // return; // uncomment here

        var e = element;
        scope.$watch(attributes.type, function(type){
          type = !!type ? type : 'span';
          var e2 = $compile('<' + type + '>' + e.html() + '</' + type + '>')(scope);
          for(var a in attributes.$attr) {
            if(a.toLowerCase() != 'type')
              e2.attr(a, attributes[a]);
          }
          e.replaceWith(e2);
          e = e2;
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

You should see "Normal Binding [number] Works" with [number] incrementing, but it's not showing.

Uncomment the return; in the link function and you will see the binding working.