# How to change element dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I can change element's attributes seamlessly like this:

```
<input
  name="{{ currentField.name }}"
  type="{{ currentField.properties.type }}"
  ... />
```

[image: There is no problem.]

But, I need to change the element (input, textarea, select etc.) dynamically.

If I try to change element, AngularJS doest not rendering the element. Instead, showing HTML:

```
<{{ currentField.element }}
  name="{{ currentField.name }}"
  type="{{ currentField.properties.type }}"
  ... />
```

[image: Doesn't rendering the element.]

This is the example {{ currentField }} data:

```
{
    element: 'textarea',
    name: 'address',
    properties: {
        type: 'text',
    }
}
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like :

```
    <textarea ng-if="currentField.element == 'textarea'"
      name="{{ currentField.name }}"
      type="{{ currentField.properties.type }}"
      ... />

<input ng-if="currentField.element == 'input'"
  name="{{ currentField.name }}"
  type="{{ currentField.properties.type }}"
  ... />
```

Comment: There are a lot of elements. Should I write this code again and again for each one?

Comment: if there lot, then then you could create a directive. here is [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24920456/creating-a-directive-with-a-variable-element-type), and [this demo](http://codepen.io/scarl3tt/pen/rsbpH) , hope it helps